# XSLT call only immediate any occurence of child nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have two possible input XMLs as below. I am looking to get only the parents account information and ignore the account under `<line>`.

Tried using `//account` and `.//account`, both return all the account segments, so respective count is 2 and 4 for each xml. expecting count is 1 and 2 `<account>`

xml1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inventory>
  <account>
    <seg1>123</seg1>
    <seg2>qwe</seg2>
  </account>
  <line>
    <account>
      <seg1>123</seg1>
      <seg2>qwe</seg2>
    </account>
  </line>
</inventory>
```

xml2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inventory>
  <accounts>
    <account>
        <seg1>123</seg1>
        <seg2>qwe</seg2>
    </account>
    <account>
        <seg1>456</seg1>
        <seg2>abc</seg2>
    </account>
</accounts>
  <line>
    <accounts>
        <account>
            <seg1>123</seg1>
            <seg2>qwe</seg2>
        </account>
        <account>
            <seg1>456</seg1>
            <seg2>abc</seg2>
        </account>
    </accounts>
 </line>
</inventory>
```

So I am expecting to read only immediate account information and ignore account under `<line>` segment

Comment: Can you show your XSLT so we can get some context on where you're trying to use those XPaths? Also, try using `//account[not(ancestor::line)]`.

Comment: your xml `  <line>' is broken

Comment: @DanielHaley The XSLT i use is really big, the example i showed is just a sample xml. Let say I am trying to get a count of accounts , expecting count of xml1 is 1 and xml2 is 2 and btw, your solution worked, Thank you verymuch.

Comment: Please show the expected output in both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to satisfy both xml 1 and 2, use

```
[not(ancestor-or-self::line)]
```

here's the **xslt**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <inventory>
            <xsl:copy-of select="//*[not(ancestor-or-self::line)]/account"/>       
        </inventory>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```